# Can you create an array of Structure inside of another structure in C language?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

Aim : To create a structure of element having certain properties. Then utilize that structure type by creating it's array in another structure.

```
struct Element
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int x;
};

struct Sparse
{
    int r;
    int c;
    int n;
    struct Element *ele;
    ele = (struct Element *)malloc(n*sizeof(struct Element));    
};
```

What I wish to know is that which part of the code am I not allowed to write while creating a structure.

Comment: `ele = (struct Element *)malloc(n*sizeof(struct Element));` needs to be in a function.

Comment: Did you try to compile the code? That will tell you pretty quickly that it is not valid. No expressions are allowed in C struct definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to do this is:

```
struct Element
{
    int i;
    int j;
    int x;
};

struct Sparse
{
    int r;
    int c;
    int n;
    struct Element ele[0];  // Make a zero length array
}; 

struct Sparse* MakeNewSparse(size_t num_ele)
{
    struct Sparse* sparse = malloc(sizeof(*sparse) + num_ele*sizeof(struct Element));
    return sparse;
}
```

This works because accessing off the end of a zero-length array is totally legal in C, ***provided*** you have allocated memory there.

In this example, we allocate enough space for the `struct Sparse`, and then enough more contiguous space for the array of `struct Element`.

After that, accessing element `sparse->ele[5]` is totally legal.

Comment: zero-length arrays are a GCC extension.  In C99, you omit the 0: `struct Element ele[];`

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
ele = (struct Element *)malloc(n*sizeof(struct Element));
```

should not be part of the struct definition - that's something you do at runtime, along these lines:

```
struct Sparse s; // create new struct Sparse instance

s.n = get_some_size();
s.ele = malloc( s.n * sizeof *s.ele );  // no need for cast
```

Answer (score 0):

`struct` in c is syntactically similar with types like `int`, `char`, etc. The definition of a `struct` is for compiler to know how to use variable declared with that `struct` such as `struct Sparse var;`. So the definition of a `struct` is not actually the code itself. It will be used at compile time.

However, `malloc()` is a function, which will be used at runtime, so it is nonsense to put `malloc()` in your `struct` definition.